# Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values

Tags: go, constants

I have a question about types of constants which are restricted to certain values and how you accomplish that in Go. Say I create a type `unary` which has two constant values `Positive(1)` and `Negative(-1)` and I want to restrict the user of that type (`unary`) from creating other values of type `unary`. Do I achieve this by creating a package and making the values `Positive` and `Negative` visible and making the type `unary` restricted to the containing package? See code below for example

```
package unary

type unary int////not visible outside of the package unary

const (
    Positive unary = 1//visible outside of the package unary
    Negative unary = -1//visible outside of the package unary
)

func (u unary) String() string {//visible outside of the package unary
    if u == Positive {
        return "+"
    }
    return "-"
}

func (u unary) CalExpr() int {//visible outside of the package unary
    if u == Positive {
        return 1
    }
    return -1
}
```

Is this the correct way to restrict a type to certain constant values?

Comment: You can look into go's source code for some ideas: [value.go](https://golang.org/src/go/constant/value.go)

Comment: For your case here: `type unary bool` as bool is two-valued in Go.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### Flaws

Your proposed solution is not safe in a way you want it to be. One can use untyped integer constants to create new values of `unary` having a different `int` value than `1` or `-1`. See this example:

```
p := unary.Positive
fmt.Printf("%v %d\n", p, p)

p = 3
fmt.Printf("%v %d\n", p, p)
```

Output will be:

```
+ 1
- 3
```

We could change `p`'s value to store the `int` value `3` which is obviously not equal to `Positive` nor to `Negative`. This is possible because [Spec: Assignability:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

> A value `x` is *assignable* to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - ...
> - `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type `T`.

`3` is an untyped constant, and it is representable by a value of type `unary` which has underlying type `int`.

In Go you can't have "safe" constants of which "outsider" packages cannot create new values of, for the above mentioned reason. Because if you want to declare *constants* in your package, you can only use expressions that have "untyped" versions–which may be used by other packages too in assignments (just as in our example).

#### Unexported struct

If you want to fulfill the "safe" part, you may use unexported `struct`s, but then they cannot be used in [constant declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations).

Example:

```
type unary struct {
    val int
}

var (
    Positive = unary{1}
    Negative = unary{-1}
)

func (u unary) String() string {
    if u == Positive {
        return "+"
    }
    return "-"
}

func (u unary) CalExpr() int {
    return u.val
}
```

Attempting to change its value:

```
p := unary.Positive

p.val = 3 // Error: p.val undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method val)

p = unary.unary{3} // Error: cannot refer to unexported name unary.unary
// Also error: implicit assignment of unexported field 'val' in unary.unary literal
```

Note that since we're now using a `struct`, we can further simplify our code by adding the `string` representation of our values to the `struct`:

```
type unary struct {
    val int
    str string
}

var (
    Positive = unary{1, "+"}
    Negative = unary{-1, "-"}
)

func (u unary) String() string { return u.str }

func (u unary) CalExpr() int { return u.val }
```

Note that this solution still has a "flaw": it uses exported global variables (more precisely package-level variables) whose values can be changed by other packages. It's true that other packages cannot create and assign *new* values, but they can do so with existing values, e.g.:

```
unary.Positive = unary.Negative
```

If you want to protect yourself from such misuse, you also have to make such global variables unexported. And then of course you have to create exported functions to expose those values, for example:

```
var (
    positive = unary{1}
    negative = unary{-1}
)

func Positive() unary { return positive }

func Negative() unary { return negative }
```

Then acquiring/using the values:

```
p := unary.Positive()
```

#### Interface

Care must be taken if you plan to use an interface type for your "constants". An example can be seen in Kaveh Shahbazian's answer. An unexported method is used to prevent others from implementing the interface, giving you the illusion that others truly can't implement it:

```
type Unary interface {
    fmt.Stringer
    CalExpr() int
    disabler() // implementing this interface outside this package is disabled
}

var (
    Positive Unary = unary(1)  // visible outside of the package unary
    Negative Unary = unary(-1) // visible outside of the package unary
)

type unary int // not visible outside of the package unary

func (u unary) disabler() {}

func (u unary) String() string { /* ... */ }

func (u unary) CalExpr() int { /* ... */ }
```

This is not the case however. With a dirty trick, this can be circumvented. The exported `Unary` type can be embedded, and an existing value can be used in order to implement the interface (along with the unexported method), and we can add our own implementations of the exported methods, doing / returning whatever we want to.

Here is how it may look like:

```
type MyUn struct {
    unary.Unary
}

func (m MyUn) String() string { return "/" }

func (m MyUn) CalExpr() int { return 3 }
```

Testing it:

```
p := unary.Positive
fmt.Printf("%v %d\n", p, p)

p = MyUn{p}
fmt.Printf("%v %d\n", p, p.CalExpr())
```

Output:

```
+ 1
/ 3
```

#### Special case

As Volker mentioned in his comment, in your special case you could just use

```
type unary bool

const (
    Positive unary = true
    Negative unary = false
)
```

As the type `bool` has two possible values: `true` and `false`, and we've used all. So there are no other values that could be "exploited" to create other values of our constant type.

But know that this can only be used if the number of constants is equal to the number of possible values of the type, so the usability of this technique is very limited.

Also keep in mind that this does not prevent such misuses when a type of `unary` is expected, and someone accidentally passes an untyped constant like `true` or `false`.

Comment: So essentially its up to the programmer to use such types in a responsible way?

Comment: @G4143 If you want simple, clean and efficient code, then basically yes. If you want safe code, then you have to resort the unexported struct type, with unexported global vars.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to just work with `int` without introducing a wrapper type: a classic way to do that in Go is using a public interface with a private function; so everybody can use it but nobody can implement it; like:

```
type Unary interface {
    fmt.Stringer
    CalExpr() int
    disabler() //implementing this interface outside this package is disabled
}

var (
    Positive Unary = unary(1)  //visible outside of the package unary
    Negative Unary = unary(-1) //visible outside of the package unary
)

type unary int //not visible outside of the package unary

func (u unary) disabler() {}

func (u unary) String() string { //visible outside of the package unary
    if u == Positive {
        return "+"
    }
    return "-"
}

func (u unary) CalExpr() int { //visible outside of the package unary
    if u == Positive {
        return 1
    }
    return -1
}
```

Others are able to set `Positive` to `nil` though; but that's not a thing in Go world - in such cases.

As @icza mentioned, one can overwrite public methods. But for private methods, Go will not call "the most shallow" one, but instead calls the original.

Comment: Be aware that an unexported method does not prevent others to implement the interface. See my answer for explanation and example.