# How to check whether the value is of type iota constant in Golang?

Tags: go, enums

I have the following type defined using iota in Golang.

```
type StatusType int

const (
    PENDING StatusType = iota
    APPROVED
    REJECTED
)
```

I want to restrict the value passed in REST-API to the StatusType. Such that the value should not exceed 0,1,2.

Comment: Detail not related to your question, but constants should not be uppercased (C style). It is Pending/Approved/Rejected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang: Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/golang-creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values)

Answer (score 12):

I do this way:
first create a package named "StatusType" (inside a folder named StatusType):
filename: $GOPATH/enum/StatusType/StatusType.go

```
package StatusType

type Int int

const (
    Pending Int = iota
    Approved
    Rejected
    end
)

func IsValid(value int) bool {
    return value < int(end)
}
```

and  use like this ($GOPATH/enum/main.go):

```
package main

import (
    "enum/StatusType"
    "fmt"
)

func Test(enum StatusType.Int) {
    fmt.Println(enum) //1
}
func main() {
    Test(StatusType.Approved)

    fmt.Println(StatusType.IsValid(1))  //true
    fmt.Println(StatusType.IsValid(10)) //false
}
```

The StatusType package just exports what you need so there is no need to check against iota const range.
Just in case you want to check, use: StatusType.IsValid()
And nice thing about StatusType package is:
When you want function parameter of StatusType type use StatusType.Int and it reveals that it is enumeration of type int.
Like:

```
Test(StatusType.Approved)
```

Comment: I think -1 would be considered valid

Answer (score 9):

Simply don't export `StatusType` (assuming you define it in package '`status`').
This follow "[What is an idiomatic way of representing enums in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989915/6309)":

```
type statusType int

const (
    PENDING statusType = iota
    APPROVED
    REJECTED
)
type StatusTyper interface {
    StatusType() statusType 
}

func(st statusType) StatusType() statusType {
    return st
}
```

Any external package would then refer to `StatusType`-like variable as `status.PENDING`, `status.APPROVED` or `status.REJECTED`.
(the only three `statusType` which implement the `StatusTyper` interface. [Caveat applies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-go#comment28204112_17989915).)

Comment: Making `StatusType` unexported and using an interface won't cut it. See a dirty trick which I presented in [Golang: Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/golang-creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values) which allows to implement interfaces even with unexported methods. In fact, no constant type can be restricted this way.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you wish for invalid JSON payloads to fail, implement the [Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface: https://play.golang.org/p/zuchzQ0vmo

Answer (score 1):

use go generate with [github.com/alvaroloes/enumer](https://github.com/alvaroloes/enumer)

```
package main

import "fmt"

//go:generate enumer -type=StatusType
type StatusType int

const (
    PENDING StatusType = iota
    APPROVED
    REJECTED
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(StatusType(0).IsAStatusType()) // true
    fmt.Println(StatusType(1).IsAStatusType()) // true
    fmt.Println(StatusType(2).IsAStatusType()) // true
    fmt.Println(StatusType(3).IsAStatusType()) // false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are another two ways to do it right without map
https://play.golang.org/p/eKW_KPshx7b

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
)

type StatusType int

const (
    PENDING StatusType = iota
    APPROVED
    REJECTED
)

func Validate(val int) (bool, error) {
    if v := StatusType(val); v > REJECTED || v < PENDING {
        return false, errors.New("invalid StatusType")
    }
    return true, nil
}

func (t StatusType) Validate() (bool, error) {
    if t > REJECTED || t < PENDING {
        return false, errors.New("invalid StatusType")
    }
    return true, nil
}


func main() {
    log.Print(Validate(-1))
    log.Print(Validate(0))
    log.Print(Validate(1))
    log.Print(Validate(3))

    log.Print(StatusType(-1).Validate())
    log.Print(StatusType(1).Validate())
    log.Print(StatusType(10).Validate())
}
```

Comment: what if someone decide to put another value after `REJECTED` ?

Answer (score 0):

the iota is merely a compiler thing. The code is equivalent to:

```
const PENDING int = 0
const APPROVED int = 1
...
```

So to design a function CheckValid() to decide if the value is among the given values.
You could either use user6169399's method if your const is in a continuous range.
Or you could simply define a var map[YOUR_TYPE_HERE]bool to validate.

```
func (t YOUR_TYPE) CheckValid(){
    if _, ok:=map[t];ok return true
    else return false
}
```