# Custom type passed to function as a parameter

Tags: go, types, type-conversion

When I define a custom type, it seems that the type of the underlying type makes a difference about whether I can pass it to a function as is or I need to convert it.

**Question is:**
Why does `RuneFunc` and `StringMap` work, but not `Integer`?

https://play.golang.org/p/buKNkrg5y-

```
package main


type RuneFunc func(rune) rune
type Integer int
type StringMap map[string]string

func main() {
    //m := make(StringMap)
    //mf(m)


    var i Integer = 5
    nf(i)


    //var f func(rune) rune
    //ff(f) 

}

func mf(i map[string]string) {

}
func ff(i func(rune)rune) {

}
func nf(i int) {

}
```

Here, when I run this function called `nf` with `Integer` it complains although `int` is the underlying type. But when I call `mf` or `ff` they run successfully.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### `Integer` and `int`

`int` and your new type `Integer` are 2 different, distinct types. Where `Integer` is expected, you have to pass a value of type `Integer`.

If you have an `Integer` value, you may use a simple type conversion to make it a value of type `int`, because the underlying type of `Integer` is `int`:

```
var i Integer = 5
nf(int(i))
```

What may be confusing and interesting at the same time is that you are allowed to pass an untyped constant without conversion:

```
nf(5)
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M4w1kKmD9A).

The reason for this is in the [Spec: Assignability:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

> A value `x` is *assignable* to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> [...]
>
> - `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type `T`.

`5` is an untyped constant which is representable by a value of type `int` because the untyped constant `5` has a [default type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) `int`, so it is representable by a value of type `Integer` (which has the same default type).

If you check the other assignability rules (not included in above quotation), none of them match the case where you attempt to pass a value of `Integer` for the parameter of type `int`, so that's not allowed.

See related question: [Golang: Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/golang-creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values/37386119#37386119)

#### `RuneFunc` and `func(rune) rune`

The difference between this case and the previous one (`Integer` and `int`) is that `int` is a [named type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and `func(rune) rune` is not.

And there's an assignability rule which allows this:

> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a [named type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types).

So in this case:

```
var f RuneFunc
ff(f)
```

`f` is a named type, but the parameter type of `ff()` is `func(rune) rune` which is unnamed, so the assignment is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your time, the question is  "Why does RuneFunc and StringMap work, but not Integer?" I've updated the main post, sorry If I didnt make my self clear.

Comment: Interesting! I never took note of that rule or what it really meant before.

Answer (score 1):

Go has a strict type system. Just because your type is merely an alias for int doesn't mean you can interchange the two freely, you'll still have to do a type conversion. Below is a working version of your main, here's the code on play ground: https://play.golang.org/p/BDTXnnG9Lg

Comment: But why it doesn't need type conversion for map[string]string or func(rune)rune? That is the question

Comment: Upvoted like the accepted very thoughtful answer of @icza, as I also did not get the extended focus of the question right at first and before clarification and because I like your code provision in the go playground combined with the terse explanation of the Integer vs. int difference.