# Why is it illegal to assign pointer to pointer for type definitions involving pointers?

Tags: pointers, go

I have the following code:

```
package main

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

type VertexPointer *Vertex

func main() {
    v := Vertex{3, 4}
    v_ptr := &v

    var test_1 *Vertex = &v
    var test_2 **Vertex = &v_ptr

    var test_3 VertexPointer = &v
    var test_4 *VertexPointer = &v_ptr
}
```

When I try and run it (I'm using Go 1.6.2) I get the following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./pointers.go:17: cannot use &v_ptr (type **Vertex) as type *VertexPointer in assignment
```

I'm confused why the assignment involving `test_3`works but not `test_4`. Based on what I've been reading, my understanding is that either both assignments should work or neither of them should work. Isn't the described behaviour a bit inconsistent?

Comment: You don't have any type aliases in your question.

Comment: A type alias is `type A = B` not `type A B`.

Comment: @leaf What do I call `type A B` then? I wanted to use `typedef` but seems like that term is not used in Go parlance.

Comment: It is called type definations. You can read the golang spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all "governed" by [Spec: Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability). Assigning to `test_3` is covered by this:

> A value `x` is assignable to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - [...]
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type.

And none of the assignability rules cover `test_4`, so it's not allowed.

The *underlying type* is detailed in [Spec: Types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)

> Each type `T` has an *underlying type*: If `T` is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is `T` itself. Otherwise, `T`'s underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which `T` refers in its [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations).

In case of `test_3`:

```
var test_3 VertexPointer = &v
```

Type of `test_3` is `VertexPointer` (explicitly specified), type of `&v` is `*Vertex`. Underlying type for both are `*Vertex`, and type of `&v` (which is `*Vertex`) is an unnamed type, so the assignment is OK. `Vertex` is a named type, but derived types such as `*Vertex` or `[]Vertex` are unnamed types.

In case of `test_4`:

```
var test_4 *VertexPointer = &v_ptr
```

Type of `test_4` is `*VertexPointer`, type of `&v_ptr` is `**Vertex` because type of `v_ptr` is `*Vertex`, not `VertexPointer`. Underlying type of `test_4` is `*VertexPoitner`, underlying type of `&v_ptr` is `**Vertex`. The underlying types do not match. So there is no assignability rule that applies, so this assignment is **not** OK.

See similar question: [Custom type passed to function as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501596/custom-type-passed-to-function-as-a-parameter/41501756#41501756)