# Can methods be created for function types?

Tags: function, go, methods

I know methods can be created for specific types

Example

```
type MyFunc func() int

func (f MyFunc) eval() int {
    return f()
}

func main() {
   var randomFunction MyFunc = func() int {
      return 1;
  }

  fmt.Println(randomFunction.eval()) // prints 1
}
```

But `randomFunction` had to be declared as with `MyFunc` type. If the declaration looked like

```
randomFunction := func() int {
  return 1;
}
```

the method call wouldn't had worked.

My question is whether methods can be created for every function with `func () int` type, for example.

I know Go is not functional, nor does contain too many functional idioms, but the I'm looking for an approach similar to Haskell's show instance for functions:

```
instance Show (Int -> Int) where
   show op = show "Function with 1 Int param and Int return type"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are "bound" to a type. `MyFunc.eval()` is bound to type `MyFunc`.

This:

```
randomFunction := func() int {
  return 1
}
```

Is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) which creates a variable with name `randomFunction` and uses a function literal to provide an initial value for it, whose type will be an anonymous function type: `func() int`. This type does not have the `eval()` function (anonymous types have zero methods).

But you may use a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert it to `MyFunc`, and the resulting value will have that method:

```
randomFunction2 := func() int {
    return 1
}
fmt.Println(MyFunc(randomFunction2).eval()) // prints 1
```

The above conversion does not change the type of `randomFucntion2` of course.

If you use the conversion in the short variable declaration, `randomFunction3` will have a static type of `MyFunc` and "always" have the `eval()` method:

```
randomFunction3 := MyFunc(func() int {
    return 1
})
fmt.Println(randomFunction3.eval()) // prints 1
```

Also note that oftentimes you don't even have to manually convert your function values, as if it is an anonymous type, the conversion will happen automatically.

For example if you have a function that takes a value of type `MyFunc`:

```
func handle(f MyFunc) {
    fmt.Println(f.eval())
}
```

You may pass the above `randomFunction2` to it:

```
handle(randomFunction2) // This is OK
```

The above works because the value of `randomFunction2` is [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to a (variable of) type `MyFunc` (they have the same base type). For details, see [Custom type passed to function as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501596/custom-type-passed-to-function-as-a-parameter/41501756#41501756).

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JN5L1m-GcAf).

Comment: Aside from this run-time conversion to `MyFunc`, can be methods created for anonymous function types?  Or only to named types as you presented?

Comment: @DanBrezeanu Methods can only be created for [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) types. [Spec: Method declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) _"[The receiver's] type must be a defined type `T` or a pointer to a defined type `T`."_