# Type definition and interface conversion

Tags: go, interface

I have tried out the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type T string

func main() {
    var a sync.Map // map[interface{}]interface{}
    var c T
    // a.Store("a", T("A"))
    a.Store("a", "A")
    b, _ := a.Load("a")
    c = b.(T)
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

This gets an error of `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not main.T`.
However, it works if I use the commented line.

Aren't `T` and `string` of same underlying types? What's behind this?

Comment: Yes, they have the same underlying type and that's why *conversion* (`T(v)`) works, however *type assertion* (`v.(T)`) is another thing.

Comment: Adding to above, the assertion is strict. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501596/custom-type-passed-to-function-as-a-parameter

Comment: If you are new to Go you do not need a sync.Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stores a `string` in the map:

```
a.Store("a", "A")
```

This loads the value from the map, but returns an interface that is pointing to the value inserted above, which is a `string`:

```
b, _ := a.Load("a")
```

This will check if `b` is a `T`:

```
c = b.(T)
```

But `b` is a `string`, so the assertion fails.

If you do:

```
a.Store("a",T("A"))
```

then the assertion should work, because the type of the value in the map is now a `T`.