# How to make a struct field be a value from list?

Tags: go

I have a list of access rights:

```
const (
    Everyone = 0
    Owner = 1
    Administrator = 2
)
```

And a struct representing Routes:

```
type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
    AccessLevel uint64
}
```

How can I restrict `AccessLevel` field value of the `Route` struct be only one of those const from above?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Golang: Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/golang-creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values/37386119#37386119).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to impose this type of restriction is by not exporting the field, and doing your checks in any setter method(s).

```
type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
    accessLevel uint64
}

// AccessLevel getter method
func (r Route) AccessLevel() uint64 {
  return r.accessLevel
}

// SetAccessLevel setter method
func (r Route) SetAccessLevel(value uint64) error {
    if value < 0 || value > 2 {
        return errors.New("AccessLevel must be between 0 and 2, inclusive")
    }
    r.accessLevel = value
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @Danilio The granularity of privacy is the package in golang. In OOP languages may be the functions of same class can access the private members here the scope is package

Comment: The `accessLevel` field can still be set directly by any code in the same package. Both of our answers fail to answer the question of the op "How can I restrict [...] field value [...] be only one of those const from above?" The real answer is: you can't. Any field that is of a type able to take consts, will be able to take other values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Go doesn't support enums. However, you can get close to it. Just introduce a separate type for your access level:

```
type AccessLevel uint64
```

and make the consts be of the type:

```
const (
    Everyone      AccessLevel = 0
    Owner                     = 1
    Administrator             = 2
)
```

Then define the Field to be of that type:

```
type Route struct {
    // ...
    AccessLevel AccessLevel
}
```

Now you can assign those consts, but not a "normal" `uint64`.

The caveat is that you can still type convert a `uint64` to a `AccessLevel` via `AccessLevel(1234)`.

Comment: I don't think this imposes the restriction which the OP was talking about. Its making the constants to be of AccessLevel type where AccessLevel type is a larger domain.

Comment: @hashcode55 I know, but the restrictions that OP want's are not possible with go.