# Enums of structs in GO

Tags: go, enums

I would like to enumerate the planets in my Go program.
Each planet includes a common name (ex: "Venus") and a distance from the sun in Astronomical Unit (ex: 0.722)

So I wrote this code :

```
type planet struct {
    commonName string
    distanceFromTheSunInAU float64
}

const(
    venus planet = planet{"Venus", 0.387}      // This is line 11
    mercury planet = planet{"Mercury", 0.722}
    earth planet = planet{"Eath", 1.0}
    mars planet = planet{"Mars", 1.52}
    ...
)
```

But Go didn't let me compile this, and gave me this error :

```
# command-line-arguments
./Planets.go:11: const initializer planet literal is not a constant
./Planets.go:12: const initializer planet literal is not a constant
./Planets.go:13: const initializer planet literal is not a constant
./Planets.go:14: const initializer planet literal is not a constant
```

Do you have any idea of how I could do?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot. Go has no const non-consts. You must either use variables or redesign.

Comment: You might like this pattern: https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-const-type-enums-iota-bc4befd096d3

Comment: See [Golang: Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/golang-creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values/37386119#37386119).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go does not support enums. You should either define your enumerated fields as `var`s or to ensure immutability, maybe use functions that return a constant result.
For example:

```
type myStruct { ID int }

func EnumValue1() myStruct { 
    return myStruct { 1 } 
}

func EnumValue2() myStruct { 
    return myStruct { 2 } 
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to namespace them? For example, so one can use `MyStructs.EnumValue1()` for example

Comment: If you place these in their own package of course @ByronCoetsee