# Representing states in Go

Tags: go, enums

We generally use Enums to represent states.

Eg, in python: we do

```
class QueueState(Enum):
    Enqueued = 1
    Processing = 2
    Processed = 3
    Dequeued = 4
```

And we can access them using `QueueState.Enqueued`, etc. The same kind of behavior is present in other languages also, like Java, C#, etc. I mean these states are kinda bound within `QueueState`.

But when it comes to declaring states in go, we use const and iota, eg:

```
type QueueState int

const (
    Enqueued QueueState = iota
    Processing
    Processed
    Dequeued
)
```

I see there is no binding of these states (Enqueued, Processing, etc) with the type `QueueState`.

To access them, I just need to use them as a constant variable.

Eg:

```
fmt.Println(Enqueued) // prints 0
```

Is there a way I can bind these states into a type and treat them as an enum as we do in other programming languages?
Eg: I wanted to use them something like this `QueueState.Enqueued`

Comment: Can you show an example of a behaviour you'd like to have but does not exist? (Besides the constants not being in their own namespace like `QueueState.Enqueued`)

Comment: @mkrieger1 nope, I just wanted to know the design we use for representing states in go, `icza` answer is a great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I see there is no binding of these states (Enqueued, Processing, etc) with the type `QueueState`.

This is not completely true. When you print its value, you see `0` printed because that's its *numerical* value. The type `QueueState` has `int` as its *underlying type*. But `Enqueued` is of type `QueueState` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gmrgE_9m4_S)):

```
fmt.Printf("%T", Enqueued) // main.QueueState
```

If you want to "visually" bound it to the `QueueState` type, include it in its name:

```
type QueueState int

const (
    QueueStateEnqueued QueueState = iota
    QueueStateProcessing
    QueueStateProcessed
    QueueStateDequeued
)
```

Then when it is referred: `QueueStateEnqueued` it becomes obvious. This naming "technique" is widely used in the standard library, some examples from the [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package:

```
const (
        MethodGet     = "GET"
        MethodHead    = "HEAD"
        MethodPost    = "POST"
        ...
)

const (
        StatusContinue           = 100 // RFC 7231, 6.2.1
        StatusSwitchingProtocols = 101 // RFC 7231, 6.2.2
        StatusProcessing         = 102 // RFC 2518, 10.1

        StatusOK                   = 200 // RFC 7231, 6.3.1
        StatusCreated              = 201 // RFC 7231, 6.3.2
        ...
)
```

If you want human-readable printed value, define a `String() string` method for it:

```
type QueueState int

func (s QueueState) String() string {
    switch s {
    case QueueStateEnqueued:
        return "Enqueued"
    case QueueStateProcessing:
        return "Processing"
    case QueueStateProcessed:
        return "Processed"
    case QueueStateDequeued:
        return "Dequeued"
    }
    return ""
}
```

Then when printed (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Vd3TS-gwVlk)):

```
fmt.Println(QueueStateEnqueued) // prints Enqueued
```

Yes, it's not very convenient to provide this `String()` method and keep it updated, hence why tools like [`stringer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) exist. They generate this `String()` method in a more compact and efficient way than the above example implementation.

There's also the option to use `string` as the enum's underlying type, and the enum values will serve as the string representation without the `String()` method (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3jcpR8ImQeW)):

```
type QueueState string

const (
    QueueStateEnqueued   QueueState = "Enqueued"
    QueueStateProcessing QueueState = "Processing"
    QueueStateProcessed  QueueState = "Processed"
    QueueStateDequeued   QueueState = "Dequeued"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(QueueStateEnqueued) // prints Enqueued
}
```

Also note that when others refer to your enum values, they do so using the package name. So you may place the enum constants in their designated package, e.g. called `queuestate`, and then you may name your constants just `Enqueued`, `Processing` etc, but when they are referred to, it will be in the form of `queuestate.Enqueued`, `queuestate.Processing` etc.

Also note that using constants only you can't restrict the values of your type. For details, see [Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values/37386119#37386119).