# How to make map to use only a set of keys

Tags: go

I want to create a map which can only have predefined keys.
for example

```
set of values be like "todo", "inprogress","done"

map[set]interface{}
```

I can think of struct will be helpful here but it will be very tedious.

Is there anything else we can use here?

Comment: Why would a struct be tedious?

Comment: See related: [Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values/37386119#37386119)

Comment: @Flimzy this is a map because _any_ value of bool can be used as the map key. (The fact that there aren't that many different bools in Go doesn't matter here) Whereas the original question talked about string keys.

Comment: @Volker: The OP appears to be (or at least may as well be) asking about an enum, represtened as strings.  I don't see any fundamental difference between an enum and any other data type with a "small number" of possible values.

Comment: @Flimzy `set = {"todo", "inprogress","done"}` doesn't look like an enum or a data type but a set of strings. Let's agree the OP is unclear and just should use a struct.

Comment: @Volker I updated the question. Basically the set meant for example, like only this set of values. It was not related to go syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two options:

1. Use a struct.
2. Perform validation on the map.

#2 may be made easier with the use of a setter method, if you wish. But fundamentally, you must validate that the keys present (or added) to match your expectations.