# Does type definition help assign restricted values?

Tags: go

In the below struct type:

```
type Employee struct {
    Name         string          `json:"name"`
    JobTitle     JobTitleType    `json:"jobtitle"`
}
```

member `JobTitle` should be ensured to have restricted(specific) values( of string type).

```
type JobTitleType string

const(
     GradeATitle JobTitleType = "Clerk"
     GradeBTitle JobTitleType = "Manager"
)
```

---

Does type definition(`JobTitleType`) help assign restricted values to member `JobTitle`?

Comment: See related / possible duplicate: [Creating a Constant Type and Restricting the Type's Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385007/creating-a-constant-type-and-restricting-the-types-values/37386119?r=SearchResults#37386119)

Answer (score 2):

No. You can assign any value to JobTitle:

```
e.JobTitle=JobTitleType("bogus")
```

The `JobTitleType` is based on string, so all string values can be converted to it.

You can use getter/setters to enforce runtime validation.

Comment: One we have getter & setter, I need to make `JobTitle` as lowercase member(`jobTitle` ) to not assign the member directly, but, this will not allow to serialize data. How to enforce that the value is assigned only through setter?

Comment: Keep it exported. There are no hard guarantees that the value will be valid.

Comment: Having member exported makes getter/setter redundant.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not restrict the values, any value that has type `JobTitleType` can be assigned to JobTitle. Currently, there is no `enum` type in Go. For restricting values you will probably need to write your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should use it in the validation logic. For example, `https://github.com/go-playground/validator` has `oneOf` operator for validation.

Go don't have `enum` type, but you can do something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var JobTitleTypes = newJobTitleTypeRegistry()

func newJobTitleTypeRegistry() *jobTitleTypeRegistry{
    return &jobTitleTypeRegistry{
        GradeATitle :  "Clerk",
        GradeBTitle : "Manager",
    }
}

type jobTitleTypeRegistrystruct {
    GradeATitle string
    GradeBTitle string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(JobTitleTypes.GradeATitle)
}
```

Comment: Instead of going for validator, this hacky approach(`jobTitleTypeRegistry`) looks better

Comment: How to assign the value of `SourceTypes` to a member of struct `Employee`?